# Changing Enumerations after declaring once c++

Tags: c++, enums, codeblocks, enumeration

I am learning c++ from the book "Jumping into c++" and after the enum and switch-case chapter it says that we should write an Tictactoe game.
I wrote the game by declaring an tictactoe enumerator including three states which are blank, o and x and declared 9 board positions as blank. but after testing the program I saw that I could not change the board positions from  blank to anything. Is that my mistake or that is the way enumerations work?

For example:

```
    enum Tictactoe{
    TTT_O, 
    TTT_X,
    TTT_Blank};
    Tictactoe Board1 = TTT_Blank;
    //goes all the way until board position 9
    int input; 
    cout << "X, chose a pile which you want to mark << endl;
    cin>> input; 
    switch (input) {
    case 1: { Tictactoe Board1 = TTT_X; break; }
    //again, goes all the way until all the board positions are checked.
```

In the code, it does print the board every 2 moves but it always shows all the boardpositions blank.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us, it will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Can you at least show what you have tried to do, as it is unclear what part of enum is unclear to you.

Comment: No, that's not how enumerations work. Yes, it's a mistake in the code.

Answer (score 4):

You want

```
case 1: { Board1 = TTT_X; break; }
```

That way you change the existing variable. With `Tictactoe Board1 = TTT_X;` you are declaring a new variable, which is then immediately destroyed.